# add document and subcolletion as batch write firebase and VUEJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I am trying to do batch write.
My goal:

1. First I want to write data which generate new collection with unique ID.
2. Then I want to add to this unique collection a subcollection of list by running forEach.

Current problem:

1. I don't know how to get this unique ID which is generated when first batch runs which I then want to parse in second batch where I create subcollection.
2. forEach doesn't work it only takes the last item from list orders.

this is my current code, note I use VUEJS3 with Pinia and for Firebase Web version 9.

```
      orders: [
        {
          id: 'id1',
          product: 'yup',
          productivity: 'nothing',
          quantity: 'lot',
        },
        {
          id: 'id2',
          product: 'Smith',
          productivity: 'huge',
          quantity: 'few',
        },
      ],
```

```
const batch = writeBatch(db);

addOrderTest() {
  const storeAuth = useStoreAuth();
  const docRef = doc(collection(db, 'users', storeAuth.user.id, 'clients', 'punTa54ogJ6wLgRmAp4Y', 'ordera'))

  batch.set(docRef, {name: 'something'})

  // here I want to add list Orders in collection which I make above, but I don't know how to get this newId, and also forEach takes only last item from table //  
  const newId = docRef.id
  this.orders.forEach((order) => {batch.set(newId, order)})


  return batch.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) for the parent document before the `batch.set()` statement and then use the new doc ID as shown below:

```
const docRef = doc(collection(db, 'users', 'storeAuth.user.id', 'clients', 'punTa54ogJ6wLgRmAp4Y', 'ordera'));

batch.set(docRef, {
  name: 'something'
})

const newId = docRef.id; 
// use this ID in DocumentReference of order documents

this.orders.forEach((order) => {
  const orderRef = doc(collection(db, 'users', storeAuth.user.id, 'clients', 'punTa54ogJ6wLgRmAp4Y', 'ordera', newId, 'order'))
  batch.set(orderRef, order);
})
```

Comment: It throws me an error: Uncaught FirebaseError: Provided document reference is from a different Firestore instance.

Comment: @BeEmil can you update your question with the latest code that you have?

Comment: I just updated question. maybe you also now what is wrong with 2nd batch command when I run forEach it only takes 2nd item.

Comment: @BeEmil the `batch.set()` takes a `DocumentReference` as first arg but you were passing the ID itself. Can you try the code in my updated answer?