# Using a batch to create a collection and a subcollection at once

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a new collection, and then create a sub collection all at once.
The code is being run when a user creates a new team and adds a players to the team. (both team and player are created/added at the same time)
This is what I have attempted so far:

```
const batch = db.batch()
const collectionRef = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('teams').doc(id)

batch.set(
  collectionRef.set({
    teamId: id,
    teamName: teamName
  })
)
batch.set(
  collectionRef.collection('players').doc(player.id).set(playerObject)
)
batch.commit().then(()=> {}).catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

The player object is defined like so:

```
{
  name: 'John Doe',
  id: '123',
  imgs: ['img.png']
  ...
}
```

But whenever this runs, only the first write is executed, the sub collection is not created. I think this is because the collection does not exist, so might cause an issue.

Comment: Can you show us the content of `playerObject`? Besides that, how is `collectionRef` defined?

Comment: Just updated it

Comment: I still cannot see where you have defined `const playerObject = ...`

Comment: The collection will show up in the console when you add a document in it. Do you get any errors in the logs? Have you tried hard coding the document data and ID in the code and see if that works?>

Comment: @User123123,do let me know if the below recommendations were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using [firestore Batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) is a better approach to do this. Create a batch and add the main document followed by the subcollection document(s).A collection is created once a document is written to it, and removed automatically once the last document is removed from it.
If you want to write the collection [parent] and the subcollection [child] in a single batch write, you can do it by generating a UniqueID for the parent document, and then creating the sub collection documents under that same path for example as below:

- Take a document document under the collection_name collection at the
  path `collection_name/document/`
- And another one sub-collection_name document under the
  subCollection_name (sub-)collection

  ```
  collection_name/document/subCollection_name/sub-collection dcoument
  ```

Also as mentioned above in the comments from Alex,use reference for the collection object while calling the object in the code to create the path for collection and sub-collection reference path, if the reference object and path is not defined the code will not work.

You may check the below examples for similar implementation:

- [How to add sub collection to firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654653/how-to-add-subcollection-to-document-in-firestore)
- [Create document and sub-collection in one shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213433/create-doc-with-subcollection-in-one-shot)
- [Add collection and subcollection as batch writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73566878/add-document-and-subcolletion-as-batch-write-firebase-and-vuejs)